# How can I render this irregular table with ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here I have a JSON data as below:

```
[
{"teacher":"Tom","student":[{"name":"stuA","project":"projectA"},{"name":"stuB","project":"projectB"}]},
{"teacher":"Jerry","student":[{"name":"stuC","project":"projectC"},{"name":"stuD","project":"projectD"},{"name":"stuE","project":"projectE"}]},
{"teacher":"Lee","student":[{"name":"stuF","project":"projectF"}]}
]
```

And now I want to render it into an irregular table like the picture:

[image]

So how can I make it possible by using ng-repeat? It's really a confusing problem.
Here is the html code that makes the table above:

```
<tr style="height:40px" >
        <td rowspan="2" style="text-align:center;background:#FFD4D4;font-weight:bold;">Tom</td>

            <td style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">stuA</td>
            <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:100px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">projectA</td>
         </tr>
   <tr style="height:40px;">
       <td style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">stuB</td>
       <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:100px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">projectB</td>
   </tr>

<tr style="height:40px">
    <td rowspan="3" style="text-align:center;background:#FFD4D4;font-weight:bold;">Jerry</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">stuC</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:100px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">projectC</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">stuD</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:100px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">projectD</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;">
    <td style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">stuE</td>
    <td style="text-align:left;padding-left:100px;font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;">projectE</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nest your repeats? You'd almost have to anyway to produce a result with the name value repeated

Comment: Sorry?I can't get your point.Could u pls explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to take use of `tbody` tag so that we need to apply to `ng-repeat` tag twice, that would do the trick for you.

**Makrup**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="teacher in teachers">
    <tr ng-repeat="student in teacher.student">
      <td ng-if="$first" rowspan="{{teacher.student.length}}">{{teacher.teacher}}</td>
      <td>{{student.name}}</td>
      <td>{{student.project}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8LhSHEObhvgLuSIzRlgo?p=preview)

Comment: Yes..maybe this is the most elegant solution.I never used the trick of $first before.Very well thanks!

Comment: Oh forgive me,I almost forgot.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` with tables/table rows can be a bit tricky. Tried to get it done, looks a bit ugly but it does the work:

```
    <tr ng-repeat-start="group in data">
      <td ng-bind="group.teacher" rowspan="{{group.student.length}}"></td>
      <td ng-bind="group.student[0].name"></td>
      <td ng-bind="group.student[0].project"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in group.student | limitTo : group.student.length - 1 : 1">
      <td ng-bind="student.name"></td>
      <td ng-bind="student.project"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/yUPEGdofvwMipcX7CpDK?p=preview

Comment: Awesome one!! I once tried start-end's trick,too but I cant find a correct way.So smart of you,man,I have been trapped in it for a whole night and you saved me.

Comment: Awesome solution..could you add more information that what is the difference by using `ng-repeat-start` & `ng-repeat-end` please update answer..+1 from me

Comment: @Levis that would not show more than two elements..looks like it has limitation

Comment: @pankajparkar The standard `ng-repeat` repeats the element and all inner html, while `ng-repeat-start/end` repeats all the html code between the start and end element (including the elemnts itself). You normally only need this, if you work with table rows, since you otherwise could just add a surrounding element and use the repeat on it.

Comment: @pankajparkar https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat Maybe this doc can help u.It shows an ng-repeat demo using start & end.

Comment: @Levis could you do look at mine answer..which would give you the exact html as you want..